# C# Excel Advanced AutoFilter to Exclude a List of Values

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, autofilter

I would like to apply an autofilter to an column in Excel using C# but would like to show only values that are **not** equal to a specified list.

The original list looks like this:

[image: Unfiltered List]

I would like filter with the following criteria `"<>apple"` and `"<>orange"`
which should result in a list that looks like this:

[image]

However, using the following code only shows the inverse of what I'm after:

```
private void ActivateAutoFilter()
        {
        this.Range["A1", "C1"].Value2 = GetArrayFromList(new List<string>() { "H1", "H2", "H3" });            
        this.Range["A2", "C2"].Value2 = GetArrayFromList(new List<string>() { "apple", "apple", "apple" });
        this.Range["A3", "C3"].Value2 = GetArrayFromList(new List<string>() { "orange", "orange", "orange" });
        this.Range["A4", "C4"].Value2 = GetArrayFromList(new List<string>() { "pear", "pear", "pear" });

        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange my_named_range = this.Controls.AddNamedRange(this.Range["A1", "C1"], "MY_NAMED_RANGE");

        string[] listFilter = new string[] { "apple", "orange" };
        my_named_range.AutoFilter(1, listFilter, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, System.Type.Missing, true);
        }
```

Inverse:

[image: Inverse Result]

Whereas, if I change the criteria from: `{ "apple", "orange" }` to: `{ "<>apple", "<>orange" }` I get an error. Any idea how I can specify a list of items to filter out of view?

Thanks in adv.!